# radarchart in R - How to increase width of a single radial axis?

Tags: r, radar-chart, spider-chart

I am trying to increase the thickness of a single radial axis on my radar chart. In this instance, I want to make my radial axis that has a value 0 thicker than other radial axes. I have highlighted the image below

```
install.packages('fmsb')
library(fmsb)


max_val = rep(2,26)
min_val = rep(-1,26)
z_score = rep(1,26)

df1 = data.frame(max_val, min_val, z_score)
final_df = data.frame(t(df1))
radarchart(final_df[, c(1,26:2)], seg = 15, axistype = 1,
           caxislabels = c(-1,-0.8,-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,
                           0, 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,
                           1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2))
```

[image: Radar Chart]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible [MRE] state the packages used and include the output of `dput(final_df[, c(1,26:2)])` in the question.

Comment: @Peter I have made changes in the code to make it a reproducible example